# Precise difference between distributed database and decentralised database

Tags: database, blockchain

Can anyone just explain me the precise difference between distributed database and decentralised database?

Answer (score 1):

**Decentralized**

It means that there is no central storage. Some servers provide information to the clients. The servers are connected with each other.

[image]

**Distributed**

There are no data storages. All the nodes contain information. The clients are equal and have equal rights.

[image]

**Main Difference**

A distributed database is a single logical database, which is installed on a set of computers that are geographically located at different locations and linked through a data communication network whereas A decentralized database is a database that is installed on systems that are geographically located at different locations but not linked through a data communication network.

Coming to Blockchain it works on Centralized Relational Database and especially Distributed Database that leverage cryptography to provide multi version concurrency control mechanism and to maintain consensus about the existence and status of shared facts in trust-less environment.

[Source](https://cointelegraph.com/explained/decentralized-and-distributed-databases-explained)

[Database in blockchain video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lf5d-R8-N20)

Comment: Is all the information get stored in each node of decentralised database ??

Answer (score 0):

The hierarchy is centralized to de-centralized to distributed.
de-centralized is simply centralized on a smaller (larger?) scale.  The risk of losing data/some catastrophic event is reduced because there are lots of little 'centers'.
Distributed databases/ledgers have no 'center'.  The risk of a catastrophic event is further reduced (although other risks (forks etc.) arise)